# Grizzly 2: how to register own SessionManager

Tags: java, session, grizzly

I'd like to replace Grizzly's builtin `DefaultSessionManager`, but I cannot find any documentation about it (other than the source code). Grizzly is running standalone as the HttpServer and Container for Jersey resources.

In `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request` I find these:

```
    /**
     * @return {@link SessionManager}
     */
    protected SessionManager getSessionManager() {
        return sessionManager != null
            ? sessionManager
            : DefaultSessionManager.instance();
    }

    /**
     * Set {@link SessionManager}, <tt>null</tt> value implies {@link DefaultSessionManager}
     * @param sessionManager 
     */    
    protected void setSessionManager(final SessionManager sessionManager) {
        this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
    }
```

Is my understanding correct that I'd have to extend `Request` in order to register my own implementation of a SessionManager? That sounds awfully complicated to me...

**Update:** As suggested, I've filed issue [GRIZZLY-1798](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1798).

Comment: Right, you can customize it only if you implement own HttpHandler, but you use one from Jersey... Can you pls. file Grizzly bug?

Comment: Ticket has been filed, could you please check it and re-classify it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been closed, and the `SessionManager` can now be registered with the `HttpServer` or a `NetworkListener`. Example:

```
HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer();
ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration = httpServer.getServerConfiguration();
serverConfiguration.setSessionManager(new MySessionManager());
```